# How to get java.sql.Connection object from Hibernate Session

Tags: java, hibernate

I have requirement where I need `java.sql.Connection`. But I am using Hibernate here. Somehow I researched and I found below alternative but that's not working.

```
import org.hibernate.connection.ProxoolConnectionProvider;
public class ConnectionDB{
    //I have imported below class 
    ProxoolConnectionProvider proxoolProvider = new ProxoolConnectionProvider();
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration cfg = HibernateUtil.getConfiguration();//this method will return configuration 
    java.util.Properties props =  cfg.getProperties();//This will return Properties Object
    //Using properties object I just tried to get The Connection Object by following method
    proxoolConn.configure(props);// I just configured the Porperties object 
    proxoolConn.getConnection();
}
```

But no luck I just end-up with no exception in console .. I am using Struts 2, Hibernate and JasperReports.

Can any one help me to get the connection object from Hibernate?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: @Muel hibernate3.jar I can see in my library..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code assumes you have an existing and open Hibernate `org.hibernate.Session`:

```
public void doWorkOnConnection(Session session) {
  session.doWork(new Work() {
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
      //use the connection here...
    }
  });
}
```

Should you need information on how to use the above classes, please read the [Hibernate 3.5 Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/). Specifically, read `Session` and then `Work`.

Comment: In Java 8 you can do ```session.doWork(connection -> yourMethodInsideDoWork(connection))``` or even ```session.doWork(this::yourMethodInsideDoWork)```

Answer (score 1):

You can also downcast the Session method into a SessionImpl and get the connection object easily:

```
SessionImpl sessionImpl = (SessionImpl) session;
Connection conn = sessionImpl.connection();
```